# Math equation equivalent to bitwise operation

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

A piece of c++ code I am reading is

```
int x = 10;
int r = 5;

auto bb = x << (r & 0x1);
```

where bb reads 20. I understand how bitwise operation works, but I have difficulty to explain its mathematical logic, say, use traditional mathematical equation to explain above. For example, << means shift. So x << n could be x^n? Then what does & mean here?

Comment: & is called the `bitwise and`. the calculation in detail: `x = 0b1010; r = 0b0101`. now `r & 0x1 = 0b0101 & 0b0001 = 1`  and then `x << 1 = 0b1010 << 1 = 0b10100 = 1*16+0*8+1*4+0*2+0*1 = 20`. see for instance http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/38-bitwise-operators/

Comment: ps. `x << n` is NOT `x^n`. (side note: in programming the hat `^` is usually a bit xor, not the mathematical power). anyways, you can use shifting to form positive powers of two only, in general: `1<<x = pow(2, x)`. a few examples: `1<<0=pow(2,0)=1;`  `1<<1=pow(2,1)=2;`  `1<<2=pow(2,2)=4`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this equation does the following:

(r & 0x1) checks for oddity of r, example :

```
 r = 5 -> 00000101 in bits
 0x1   -> 00000001 in bits

 r & 0x1->00000001 since its only 1 if both bits are one.
```

so this term results in 1 if r is odd, and 0 if r is even.

now we shift with this value (either 1 or 0) left.

```
 n << 0/1 

 n = 10:   00001010
 n << 1    00010100
```

so this term gets doubled (shift left) if r is odd, explaining the result

Answer (score 2):

`r & 0x1` is a bitwise AND between `r` and `1`. This is essentially equivalent to checking if `r` is even or odd.

The statement preforms a bit shift of `1` if `r` is odd or does nothing (bit shift of 0) if `r` is even. Left shifting an integer by `n` is equivalent to multiplying it by `2^n`. So in this case, it doubles the `x` if `r` is odd.

Answer (score 2):

& is the bitwise and-operator

`r & 0x1` results in 1 if the last bit is set (i.e. if r is odd), and in 0 if the last bit is not set (r is even).

The left shift by n corresponds to a multiplication by 2^n.

As r = 5 is odd the left shift by 1 is perfomed, resulting in 10 * (2^1) = 20

Answer (score 2):

```
auto bb = x << (r & 0x1);
```

can be translated to English as:

If `r` is odd, initialize `bb` to `x * 2`.
If `r` is even, initialize `bb` to `x`.

`r & 0x1` is `1` if `r` is odd and `0` if `r` is even.

`x << 1` is equal to `x * 2`.
`x << 0` is equal to `x`.

Comment: Very straightforward answer! With jonas_toth's explanation in depth, I now understand bitwise operation!

Comment: @Kyle, glad I was able to help you understand bitwise operations a bit better.